# Change .NET App's Assembly Resolve Location

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to modify 2 .exes to load DevExpress dlls from 1 location.

The .exes in the "Products" folder are use the same .dlls as the launcher does. I want to avoid having to put the same .dlls into the Products directory, and instead have the .exes read from 1 directory back(the launchers directory).

How can I achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event and load the assemblies from the directory yourself using Assembly.LoadFile giving the fullpath to the assembly it is trying to resolve.

Example:

```
.
.
.
// elsewhere at app startup time attach the handler to the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
.
.
.

private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);

    // this.ReadOnlyPaths is a List<string> of paths to search.
    foreach (string path in this.ReadOnlyPaths)
    {
        // If specified assembly is located in the path, use it.
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
             string fileNameWithoutExt = fileInfo.Name.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, "");                    

             if (assemblyName.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == fileNameWithoutExt.ToUpperInvariant())
             {
                  return Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(fileInfo.FullName));
             }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is my Program.cs file: pastebin.com/Qkr08HCv If i put all of he DevExpress files into the DevExpress folder and run Form1 outside of it, it does not open unless i put the dlls back in the same location as the form. I put a MessageBox("Test") at the very top of Main() and it does not fire when the .dlls are not in the same folder as the exe, so I am unable to call the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve; from there

Comment: It depends on when it tries to load those types. You have to be able to register the event handler before the DevExpress types have to be resolved.

Comment: It looks like because you are referencing DevExpress types directly in your Main method, it has to load those types before your AssemblyResolve handler is registered

Comment: the Main() does not even fire without the DevExpress files though. Is there anywhere sooner I can put this?

http://puu.sh/jQIGX/644ab03efa.png, the MessageBox does not even display without the DevExpress stuff in the main folder, so I can't put it there

Comment: In your Program class create a static method called InitializeDevExpressSkins(). Then move all of the calls to the DevExpress types into that method. Then Call InitializeDevExpressSkins from Main. This should delay the types from being loaded.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that about did it! I had to put the application to run inside of the Initialize method since it was firing too early. Works like a charm now

Comment: After doing this and uploading the file, when people download it it stops working. I am able to make it work by manually transferring the program to them, but if they download it from anywhere it no longer opens unless I put the files back into the original directory. Any idea?

Comment: How are you deploying it? Plus this might qualify as a separate question on SO :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may set folder(s) path in assemblyBinding>probing::privatePath tag in app.config for the common language runtime to search when loading assemblies.
like this code

[Reference MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="libs" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace myNamespace
{
    public sealed class EntryPoint
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
            var app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }
        private static Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            // do whatever necessary...
        }
    }
}
```

As WPF already has a built-in `Main()` method, you will get a compiler error. So go to project properties > Application > "Startup object" and set it to `myNamespace.EntryPoint`. In your own `Main()` method, you have full control over everything, so you can set the `AssemblyResolve` handler before instantiating the `App`.