How to tell my application to look in specific folders for dlls
I am writing a .net framework 4.8.1 application that references about 2 dozen dlls from a couple of different third party applications. Those dlls in turn reference many more (thousands) dlls from those applications. The third party applications are very large Machine Vision/AI software programs. In order for my application to run, I need to copy the entire programs to my bin folder otherwise I get dll not found errors.
Program 1 is 6GB and Program 2 is 4GB, so my bin folder will about 10GB in size, on my development PC thats 10GB in the debug folder, 10GB in the release folder, and I have about 50 different such programs that will be in development that all need to do this, requiring around a TB of space. I'm starting to run out of disk space. How can I tell my application to look in these folders for any extra dlls and references, and when I deploy this software it will do the same on the deployed system. This is software for industrial automation, so it will only be deployed on 1 single PC that is tightly controlled and setup by me.
C:\My Application Folder
C:\Program Files\Application 1
C:\Program Files\Application 2


Handle the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event, and include your search paths in there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32253965/832052

Are they all managed, or are there unmanaged libraries as well?  Managed libraries are easy to handle as per the previous comment.  Unmanaged are more difficult and may partly need the libraries themselves to help out.

If your project includes a reference to the given assemblies, then at build time, all the required .dll's should automatic copy to the bin folder at build time. In other words, DO NOT place .dll's that you reference in the bin folder, but use valid references to such assemblies, and at build time, they all should automatic copy to bin folder - including their dependent .dll's. So, don't over time start dropping .dll's into the bin folder and reference them that way - let the build process do that for you. You CAN have multiple separate projects in one main project, but references is better

Thanks djv, that led me to a path that works, but its cludgy.
I ended up adding this code to my Application.xaml.vb file. It seems like there should be a better easier way of doing this though.
Class Application

    Private ReferenceFolders As New List(Of String) From {"C:\Program Files\Program 1"} , "C:\Program Files\Program 2"}



    Private Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) 'Handles Me.Startup

        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve
        ' other stuff
    End Sub

    Private Sub Application_Exit(sender As Object, e As ExitEventArgs) Handles Me.[Exit]
        ' other stuff
        RemoveHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve
    End Sub

    Private Function CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(sender As Object, args As ResolveEventArgs) As Assembly
        Dim myAssemblyName As New AssemblyName(args.Name)

        Dim dllPath As String = FindFile(ReferenceFolders, myAssemblyName.Name & ".dll")
        If dllPath <> "" Then
            Return Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllPath))
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Function FindFile(folders As List(Of String), filename As String) As String
        For Each folderPath In folders
            Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)

            Dim fileList = dirInfo.GetFiles(filename, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            For Each file In fileList
                If String.Equals(filename, file.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                    Return file.FullName
                End If
            Next
        Next

        Return ""
    End Function

End Class

I did try this below in app.config, but it didn't work.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
        <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="C:\Program Files\Program 1" />
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="C:\Program Files\Program 2" />
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>

My code references managed dlls, located in different program files folders (I don't reference from my bin folder), but those dlls do reference unmanaged dlls. I was using a post build copy routine to copy the other dlls and files from the program files to my bin folder so that it would work, but now i removed to that post build copy and can keep my bin folder significantly smaller. But if someone has a better on way of how to do this then my method here, that would be good to know.

After further testing this did not work. My program crashes with the error "Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: cannot load mkl_vml_avx512.dll"  This mkl_vml_avx512.dll is in the C:\Program Files\Application 1\  folder, but it never comes up in the AssemblyResolve event so I'm stuck :(
